# OS X only picks up 1 of 3 DNS servers from DHCP on DD-WRT

Tags: macos, dns, dhcp, dd-wrt

I am running a DD-WRT router, and in the "Network Address Server Settings (DHCP)" section on the "Basic Setup" page, I have entered values for "Static DNS 1", "Static DNS 2", and "Static DNS 3".

On my Mac running OS X 10.9.5, configured to use DHCP, when I look in the DNS tab, I only see the first of those DNS servers listed.

Am I misunderstanding something, or is this a limitation of the DHCP client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure in the same "static DNS" page, you have `Use DNSMasq for DNS` option enabled. In this way the client's DNS server will be the same as the dd-wrt's IP, and dd-wrt will relay DNS query to these static DNS to get the final result.
2. If you want the client to use the ISP DNS server directly, after enabling `Use DNSMasq for DNS` option, put all 0 in the static DNS field, then put below line in Additional DNSmasq options box(this is in Services->Services page), where x.x.x.x and y.y.y.y are DNS server's. Please check [dd-wrt wiki](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/DNSMasq_as_DHCP_server#ISP_DNS-Servers) for more info.

> dhcp-option=6, x.x.x.x, y.y.y.y

Comment: Interesting. what I was really aiming for is… Have clients use the DD-WRT as primary, fall back to the ISP, and then to a Tier 2. Have the DD-WRT use the ISP as primary, and then fall back to a Tier 2.

Comment: @SteveJorgensen OS X doesn't do DNS fallback. If you give it three DNS servers (e.g. the router, ISP, and tier 2), it will just go ahead and use all three.

Comment: Thanks. I did not understand that was the case.

Comment: This does not answer at all the original question which is why does OS X client see only the first out of three DNS servers configured in DD-WRT?